# How do I create a Canadian postal code range generator in C#

Tags: c#

I've been trying for the past 24 hours to come up with a tool that will output all the postal codes between a set of Canadian postal codes.

Let's say the begin is A1A1A1 and the end is A1A1B3.

I need it to spit out a list like the below

- A1A1A1
- A1A1A2
- A1A1A3
- A1A1A4
- A1A1A5
- A1A1A6
- A1A1A7
- A1A1A8
- A1A1A9
- A1A1B0
- A1A1B1
- A1A1B2
- A1A1B3

Canadian postal codes can't contain the letters D, F, I, O, Q, or U, and cannot start with W or Z:

```
[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]
```

Any help?

Edit:

Here is some of my code (it's not a lot). First, I wrote a small class that will give me valid Canadian letters with some sort of ID/order. I'm thinking that this will be used to help find the next letter when I increment. My first thought is i could use some sort of recursion method so i don't have to code all the If/Else cases.

```
    public class CanadaLetters
    {
        public int i { get; set; }
        public string letter { get; set; }
    }

  public CanadaLetters[] CLetters = new CanadaLetters[]{
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 1, letter = "A"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 2, letter = "B"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 3, letter = "C"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 4, letter = "E"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 5, letter = "G"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 6, letter = "H"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 7, letter = "J"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 8, letter = "K"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 9, letter = "L"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 10, letter = "M"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 11, letter = "P"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 12, letter = "R"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 13, letter = "S"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 14, letter = "T"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 15, letter = "V"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 15, letter = "W"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 16, letter = "X"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 17, letter = "Y"},
        new CanadaLetters() {i = 17, letter = "Z"},
    };
```

This is the start of my code. I figured i'd break the postal code into a string array and work backward.

```
        var begin = "A1A1A1";
        var end = "Z9Z9Z9";


        while (begin != end)
        {
            var postalCode = begin.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();

            for (int i = postalCode.Length; i < 0; i--)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(postalCode[i], out var ii))
                {
                    if (ii == 9)
                    {
                        postalCode[i] = "0";

                    }
                }
            }

            tbAllPostalCodes.Text += begin + Environment.NewLine;


        }
```

Comment: You have 3 pairs of type LETTER + NUMBER. Start with making such a pair.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Could you post the code you have written in the last 24 hours, pls ;)

Comment: @isma sure. Just did. Not sure it will be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight-forward solution can be like this

```
private static readonly char[] LegalChars = {
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
};

// Credits to @Toni for notifying me about this part of the the specs
private static readonly char[] LevelOneForbiddenChars = { 'W', 'Z' };

public static IList<string> GetLetterNumberPairs(string stopAt, bool firstLevel = false)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    foreach (var currentChar in LegalChars)
    {
        if (firstLevel && LevelOneForbiddenChars.Contains(currentChar))
        {
            continue;
        }

        for (var j = 1; j < 10; j++)
        {
            var currentLetterAndNumber = $"{currentChar}{j}";
            result.Add(currentLetterAndNumber);
            if (stopAt.Equals(currentLetterAndNumber))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

[Test]
public void PostalCodeTest()
{
    foreach (var level1 in GetLetterNumberPairs("A1", true))
    {
        foreach (var level2 in GetLetterNumberPairs("A1"))
        {
            foreach (var level3 in GetLetterNumberPairs("B3"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{level1}{level2}{level3}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A1A1A1
A1A1A2
A1A1A3
A1A1A4
A1A1A5
A1A1A6
A1A1A7
A1A1A8
A1A1A9
A1A1B1
A1A1B2
A1A1B3
```

Not sure about your specs for `0`.

Comment: Hello @roar-s. The postal codes cannot start with `W` or `Z`. You did not cover that part of the question.

Comment: @Toni: Added credits to you in my answer, thanks again. BR